# jQuery aToolTip plugin only works on the title of links, how do I get it to work with titles on images, fields and spans too?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tooltip

My current tooltips only work on the titles of links, not on the titles of images, fields, or spans - how do I get the tooltips to work on all titles?

Here is the aToolTip JS:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.aToolTip = function(options) {
        /**
            setup default settings
        */
        var defaults = {
            // no need to change/override
            closeTipBtn: 'aToolTipCloseBtn',
            toolTipId: 'aToolTip',
            // ok to override
            fixed: true,
            clickIt: false,
            inSpeed: 200,
            outSpeed: 100,
            tipContent: '',
            toolTipClass: 'defaultTheme',
            xOffset: 5,
            yOffset: 5,
            onShow: null,
            onHide: null,

        },
        // This makes it so the users custom options overrides the default ones
        settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        return this.each(function() {
            var obj = $(this);
            /**
                Decide weather to use a title attr as the tooltip content
            */
            if(obj.attr('title')){
                // set the tooltip content/text to be the obj title attribute
                var tipContent = obj.attr('title');  
            } else {
                // if no title attribute set it to the tipContent option in settings
                var tipContent = settings.tipContent;
            }

            /**
                Build the markup for aToolTip
            */
            var buildaToolTip = function(){
                $('body').append("<div id='"+settings.toolTipId+"' class='"+settings.toolTipClass+"'><p class='aToolTipContent'>"+tipContent+"</p></div>");

                if(tipContent && settings.clickIt){
                    $('#'+settings.toolTipId+' p.aToolTipContent')
                    .append("<a id='"+settings.closeTipBtn+"' href='#' alt='close'>close</a>");
                }
            },
            /**
                Position aToolTip
            */
            positionaToolTip = function(){
                $('#'+settings.toolTipId).css({
                    top: (obj.offset().top - $('#'+settings.toolTipId).outerHeight() - settings.yOffset) + 'px',
                    left: (obj.offset().left + obj.outerWidth() + settings.xOffset) + 'px'
                })
                // added delay() call...
                .stop().delay(1000).fadeIn(settings.inSpeed, function(){
                    if ($.isFunction(settings.onShow)){
                        settings.onShow(obj);
                    }
                }); 

            var $tooltip = $('#' + settings.toolTipId),
                $win = $(window),
                winLeft = $win.scrollLeft(),
                objWidth = obj.outerWidth(),
                tipWidth = $tooltip.outerWidth(),
                offset = obj.offset(),
                ttWidth = $tooltip.outerWidth(),
                ttHeight = $tooltip.outerHeight();
        $win.width() < (offset.left - winLeft + objWidth + tipWidth + ttWidth) ?
            $tooltip  //reversed (to left)
                .addClass("reversed")
                .css({
                    left: offset.left - winLeft - tipWidth - ttWidth,
                    top: offset.top - $win.scrollTop() + obj.outerHeight() / 2 + ttHeight
     })
          :
           $tooltip //standard (to right)
            .css({
               left: offset.left - winLeft + objWidth + ttWidth,
                top: offset.top - $win.scrollTop() + obj.outerHeight() / 2 + ttHeight
     });            
            },
            /**
                Remove aToolTip
            */
            removeaToolTip = function(){
                // Fade out
                $('#'+settings.toolTipId).stop().fadeOut(settings.outSpeed, function(){
                    $(this).remove();
                    if($.isFunction(settings.onHide)){
                        settings.onHide(obj);
                    }
                });             
            };

            /**
                Decide what kind of tooltips to display
            */
            // Regular aToolTip
            if(tipContent && !settings.clickIt){    
                // Activate on hover    
                obj.hover(function(){
                    // remove already existing tooltip
                    $('#'+settings.toolTipId).remove();
                    obj.attr({title: ''});
                    buildaToolTip();
                    positionaToolTip();
                }, function(){ 
                    removeaToolTip();
                }); 
            }           

            // Click activated aToolTip
            if(tipContent && settings.clickIt){
                // Activate on click    
                obj.click(function(el){
                    // remove already existing tooltip
                    $('#'+settings.toolTipId).remove();
                    obj.attr({title: ''});
                    buildaToolTip();
                    positionaToolTip();
                    // Click to close tooltip
                    $('#'+settings.closeTipBtn).click(function(){
                        removeaToolTip();
                        return false;
                    });      
                    return false;           
                });
            }

            // Follow mouse if enabled
            if(!settings.fixed && !settings.clickIt){
                obj.mousemove(function(el){
                    $('#'+settings.toolTipId).css({
                        top: (el.pageY - $('#'+settings.toolTipId).outerHeight() - settings.yOffset),
                        left: (el.pageX + settings.xOffset)
                    });
                });         
            }           

        }); // END: return this
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Here is the JavaScript in my header that I use to fire it: I tried modified it to try and limit the tool tips to two possible alternates, the pretty tooltip plugin, and a simple "tooltipquestion" class for more detailed tips.

```
$(function() {
$("a:not(.tooltipquestion)").aToolTip({ 
        closeTipBtn: 'aToolTipCloseBtn',  
        toolTipId: 'aToolTip',  
    fixed: false,                   // Set true to activate fixed position
        clickIt: false,                 // set to true for click activated tooltip
inSpeed: 400,                   // Speed tooltip fades in   --chris/peter 12/9
        outSpeed: 400,                  // Speed tooltip fades out  
        tipContent: '',                 // Pass in content or it will use objects 'title' attribute  
        toolTipClass: 'defaultTheme',   // Set class name for custom theme/styles  
        xOffset: 15,                     // x position  
        yOffset: -50,                     // y position  
        onShow: null,                   // callback function that fires after atooltip has shown  
        onHide: null                    // callback function that fires after atooltip has faded out      
    });  
        });
```

The CSS for the tooltips is a follows:

```
#aToolTip {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    z-index: 50000;
    max-width: 350px;
    collision: flipfit flip;

}

    #aToolTip .aToolTipContent {
        position:relative;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        max-width: 350px;
        collision: flipfit flip;
    }
    #aToolTip span {
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        z-index: 50000;
}
    #aToolTip .aToolTipContent span {
    position:relative;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
}

/* 
    END: Required Styles
*/
/**
    Default Theme
*/
.defaultTheme {
    border:2px solid #444;
    background:#555;
    color:#fff;
    margin:0;
    padding:6px 12px;   
    font-family: 'Archivo Narrow', sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;    
    -moz-border-radius: 0 12px 12px 12px ;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 12px 12px 12px ;
    -khtml-border-radius: 0 12px 12px 12px ;
    border-radius: 0 12px 12px 12px ;

/*
    -moz-border-radius: 12px 12px 12px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px 12px 12px 0;
    -khtml-border-radius: 12px 12px 12px 0;
    border-radius: 12px 12px 12px 0;

    -moz-border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 0;
    -khtml-border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 0;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 0;
*/
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #111; /* for Firefox 3.5+ */
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #111; /* for Safari and Chrome */
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #111; /* for Safari and Chrome */
}

    .defaultTheme #aToolTipCloseBtn {
        display:block;
        height:18px;
        width:18px;
        background:url(../images/closeBtn.png) no-repeat;
        text-indent:-9999px;
        outline:none;
        position:absolute;
        top:-20px;
        right:-30px;
        margin:2px;
        padding:4px;
    }
```

Here is an example of some HTML that has several tooltips - a working  title, a working  with class="tooltipquestion", and a non-working  title that I would like the jQuery plugin to work on:

```
<tr>
      <td class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="paramId[]" id="paramId[]" /></td>
      <td class="open"><a href="questions_edit.asp" title="View this question">Biology, lab, meth</a></td>
        <td class="open">Haney, M</td>
        <td class="open">Draft</td>
        <td class="open">M/C</td>
        <td class="action" nowrap="nowrap"><a href="#" class="tooltipquestion" title= "<strong>Plant leaves appear green because they ____ light spectrum. </strong>

    <br><b>a.)</b>&nbsp;Scatter all colors except the green portion of the visible.
    <br><b>b.)</b>&nbsp;Scatter the green portion of the visible.
    <br><b>c.)</b>&nbsp;Absorb the green portion of the visible.
    <br><b>d.)</b>&nbsp;Scatter the green portion of the ultraviolet. ">Preview</a></td>
        <td class="action" nowrap="nowrap"><a href="questions_edit.asp" title="Edit this question"><img src="Icons/edit-green.gif" alt="Edit Question" title="Edit Question" width="16" height="16" border="0" /></a>&nbsp;<a href="questions_listing.asp?confirmation=1"><img src="Icons/delete.png" alt="Delete Question" title="Delete Question" width="16" height="16" border="0" /></a></td>
    </tr>
```

How do I adjust my code to allow for tooltips to also fire on  and  titles as well as the already working ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to target the different elements. At the moment you are targeting any anchor that doesnt have this class...

```
.tooltipquestion
```

Ideally what you want to do is, for any element you want to have the tooltip applied to, you give it a class

```
.tooltip
```

You then initialize the plugin with this class as the target selector...

```
$('.tooltip').aToolTip();
```

You then need to give any 'tooltip' elements a title attribute...

```
<span title="This is a span tag..." class="tooltip">Some text</span>
```

You then do the same with any other elements.

Comment: So I would add to my CSS something like:
span.tooltip { enter the tooltips current css; }?
img.tooltip { " " "}?
input.tooltip { " " "}?

Comment: Sooooo, if my tooltip css is based on jQuery plugin pulling .defaultTheme {}, I need to adjust to span.defaultTheme {}, img.defaultTheme {}, and input.defaultTheme {}, right?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help you:

```
$('*[title]').each(function() {
    this.aToolTip(...);
}​);​
```

This code applies for each element that has a title.